# how to run imacros sript on each chrome tab independently

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

I'm using
chrome Version 115.0.5790.171 (Official Build) (64-bit)
windows 8 and windows 10

my question is "how to run imacros script on each chrome tab independently"

i did not found out anything for testing.
thank you for helping me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on topic in the [help/on-topic]. SO is only for _programming_ questions.